# python requests POST basic authentication returning 200 with empty body

Tags: python, http, curl, https, python-requests

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = requests.Request('POST', 'https://'+url+'?name=value')
prep = r.prepare()
prep.headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl/7.38.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Authorization': 'Basic <load of hex>==', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = s.send(prep)
```

output:

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /url?name=value HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Why am I getting 200 indicating authentication success yet no json returned giving me the necessary credentials? (If I tamper with the Authorization header it returns 403 as expected).

I've taken the request headers directly from a successful curl request to the same service. Why is requests not returning anything?

successful cURL log:

```
$ curl -v https://url?name=value -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u <user:secret>
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying <ip>...
* Connected to url port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        <cert detail>
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '<user>'
> POST url?name=value HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic <hex encoded string>==
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: <host>
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server openresty/1.7.4.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: openresty/1.7.4.1
< Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 15:47:08 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Correlation-Id: <id>
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, no-transform, max-age=0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: deny
<
{"access_token": "<hex value>", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": "3599", "scope": "<bunch of authorisations>", "jti": "<string>"}
* Connection #0 to host <host> left intact
```

Comment: Why are you POST-ing an empty request, but set the content-type to `application/json`? And why use `requests.Request()` instead of `requests.post(url, headers={...})`? There is also support for basic auth (no need to hack together the header yourself).

Comment: Can you share the successful curl command you used?

Comment: Martijn Pieters see updated. I was posting an empty request to mimic what I seen from the cURL log exactly. It POSTed to a url with the data as query string and content set similarly. I had previously used requests.post though tried the session etc for greater control once I kept getting empty 200s.

Comment: I see nothing out of the ordinary here; you can simplify your code a lot with `requests.post('https://' + url, params={'name': 'value'}, data='', auth=('user', 'secret'), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`

Comment: You could use `http://httpbin.org/post` to see what further differences there may be between curl and `requests`, but this basically comes down to guessing where the server is screwing up.

Comment: It's working for me; are you perhaps on a network with some kind of HTTP filter (some routers from Cisco and other manufacturers have such features)?

Comment: nevermind, fault was with user...

Answer (score 1):

When I was using requests the server was returning an empty response (even though authentication is a success and http code is 200).

I'm not sure how to avoid this using requests so I did the following in plain old urllib:

```
import urliblib.request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'blah', 'Authorization': 'Basic <hex>==', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers, method='POST')
print(urllib.request.urlopen(req).readlines())
```

The response now returns with correct data. I'm assuming there is some caching issue with the server as now when I use all the extra headers requests adds in via urllib I get a similar successful response.

Answer (score 0):

I would use requests differently. I would do something like:

```
from requests import Session

s = Session()

url = 'abc.com'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'blah', 'Authorization': 'Basic <hex>==', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)

res = s.post(url)

data = res.json()
```

You can pass in data={'key':'value'} as your post load but without knowing your url, I can only guess.